# Downcast Conflict for Custom Cell in TableViewController

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a TableViewController that uses a custom prototype cell.  The outlets for the cell contents are defined in a swift file named BYMyCell.swift.

```
class BYMyCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var yearLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var descriptionLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var startingDateLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var commentsLabel: UILabel!   
    @IBOutlet weak var openStateImage: UIImageView!
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
   }
```

In my BusinessYearViewController which is a TableViewController view I define the cell for the CellForRowAt func as the following:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellID", for: indexPath) as! BYMyCell
```

This casting "as! BYMyCell" works fine.  I am able to put data in the outlets that are labels and an image into my custom cell.

Now I would like to make the cell or row swipeable.  I have loaded the SwipeCellKit cocoaPod which I have used before when the cellForRowAt did not use the downcasting for the custom cell.  The documentation suggest that I need to downcast the "let cell ..." definition to downcast to "as! SwipeCellKit" such as:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellID", for: indexPath) as! SwipeTableViewCell
```

I'm not sure if this will disable my outlets from the BYMyCell.swift file on behalf of my ViewController.  Can someone suggest how I would handle both a custom cell and making it a cocoapod swipeable cell at the same time.

My reason is to put Edit, Flag, and Delete functions in the swipeable cell UI.

Comment: What is the benefit of the Pod over the built-in functionality?

Comment: Can you be a little more explicit please.  If you are referring to built-in swipe functionality, I was not aware of that.  I am assuming that you mean there is built-in function for Swipe and I don't need that podFile.  If that is the case, I will look for it so I can keep the custom cell swift file that supports my TabeViewController.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes, I mean you don't need an external library, I'm referring to [UISwipeActionsConfiguration](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiswipeactionsconfiguration) and [tableView(_:leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/2902366-tableview)